# django orm take to much time in mysql and server

Tags: django, django-models

we have a script in django and this script loop on the csv rows and add csv rows to the database.
when we do it in local and with sqlite script do the job so fast but when we do it in server and with mysql it take too much time.
I debug the script and I found out after some row when we reach line of getting first object it takes to much time for response
code:

```
filtered=Stock_Csv.objects.filter(ticker=name)
filtered_by_date=filtered.filter(date=date_object)
current_obj=filtered_by_date.first()
```

when reach this line:`current_obj=filtered_by_date.first()` it takes to much time for response

but it's just happened in mysql and in local we don't have this problem.

Comment: First, does the code snippet run on mysql or is this just parsing the csv file? If this code is for mysql, then you need to capture and analyse the underlying sql code to understand how to speed it up.

Comment: Have you tested it out with multiple queries? The snippet you show would only make one query to the database. One of the reasons Django might take time can be that the query is the _first_ query made to the database after the server started (hence Django needs to setup a connection which might take time), subsequent queries would be much faster since Django will then reuse existing connections.

Comment: script just parsing the csv file and save each row in database.how I do it with subsequent queries?